# ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

I get an error in my code:

ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

This could be due to the line in this code:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('" + theUserId + "' , '" + fileuploadpath + "')");
```

Full code:

```
{
    string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
    {
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;");
        cn.Open();
    }
    if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            //FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + filename);
            string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/");
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Path.Combine(fileuploadpath, filename));
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";



            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('" + theUserId + "' , '" + fileuploadpath + "')");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;

        }

    }
}

        }
```

There is another problem, I dont think its an insert I want as this is going to make a duplicate entry within my database, would it just be a case of changing it from INSERT INTO to UPDATE?

Also is there a way to overwrite upon uploading the image? Atm it just saving the image into the same folder as the one I already have? The first image or any image obviously isnt going to have the same file name so how would I go about overwriting any image in the folder with the one im uploading?

**EDIT:**

New error (fileupload works as its stored in the correct area but passing the fileupload to the insert statement is abit wonky)

I get the error

The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.5.9]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''C:\Users\Garrith\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\userdata\1\uplo' at line 1

Which is kind of strange?

All im trying to do is save the filepath+filename in mydb my attempt at passing to the insert has obviously failed.

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
            OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;");
            cn.Open();
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            //FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + filename);
            string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/");
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Path.Combine(fileuploadpath, filename));
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
            //some kind of function to take the path then enter it into my insert syntax?
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('" + theUserId + "' , '" + fileuploadpath + "')", cn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
        }
```

As you can see on this line:

```
VALUES ('" + theUserId + "' , '" + fileuploadpath + "')", cn);
```

im missing the "filename" i tryed this:

```
VALUES ('" + theUserId + "' , '" + fileuploadpath, filename + "')", cn);
```

Cheap shot lol but worth a go I guess and it cryed as it always does!

Comment: You have a few issues.  The command must be associated with the connection.  Also, passing the fileuploadpath as value in the insert will not work.  You need to read the file (File.ReadAllBytes) and pass the byte[] as a argument to the insert.

Comment: He's not trying to store the file bytes in the database... just the path to wherever he's saving it.

Comment: yeah antisanity is correct, but im gettin an error again, something new will update post

Comment: Your second error might be because you are not properly escaping the path. A better approach would be to use OdbcParameters, which should take care of the escaping for you.

Comment: @Garrith: If you're referring to me, then I already did... =]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to create the `OdbcCommand` using `CreateCommand` on `OdbcConnection`.  The code as posted does not tie `cmd` to `cn`.  Also, you should use CommandParameters instead of inlining the values (to guard against SQL injection attacks).

```
OdbcCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES (?, ?)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@UserID", OdbcType.Int, theUserID));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@picturepath", OdbcType.VarChar, fileuploadpath));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to associate the connection with the cmd:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = 
  new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('" + theUserId + "' , '" + fileuploadpath + "')");       

cmd.Connection = cn;  // <--------

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, remove the braces here:

```
{         
    OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; 
    Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;");          cn.Open(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('" + theUserId + "' , '" + fileuploadpath + "')");  <--- there is no connection intialize here
```

Change it to:

```
    //eg: odbconnection cn = new odbcconnection();

string fileup = fileupload + "," filename;


    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('" + theUserId + "' , '" + fileup.ToString() + "')",cn);
```

Regards

Comment: yeah I spotted that when I changed my connection string and session string inside the try statement thanks tho (i took it out because i had placed the connection string outside of the try)

Comment: check my edit...add breakpoint to the line file up..and check if your filepath + filename is pass into fileup. so there will be no problem on insert.

Answer (score 1):

The following is syntactically fubar'd:

```
string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
{
    OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;");
    cn.Open();
}
```