# How to store unicode character in oracle database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, unicode, oracle10g

I'm Trying to store Unicode data (Hindi Language character) in oracle database instead of storing in hindi character it stored in this format ????

I'm using Oracle 10g and i have set database character set to AL32UTF8
my table script

```
create table UTF
(
 ENGLISH_NAME VARCHAR2(10),
 HINDI_NAME   NVARCHAR2(10)
)
```

I'm using visual studio 13

I'm using google API for translation

```
<script>
function OnLoad() {
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage:
        google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage:
        [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
    };

    var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
    control.makeTransliteratable(["txtHindi"]);
    var keyVal = 32; // Space key
    $("#txtEnglish").on('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 32) {
            var engText = $("#txtEnglish").val() + " ";
            var engTextArray = engText.split(" ");
            $("#txtHindi").val($("#txtHindi").val() + engTextArray[engTextArray.length - 2]);

            document.getElementById("txtHindi").focus();
            $("#txtHindi").trigger({
                type: 'keypress', keyCode: keyVal, which: keyVal, charCode: keyVal
            });
        }
    });

    $("#txtHindi").bind("keyup", function (event) {
        setTimeout(function () { $("#txtEnglish").val($("#txtEnglish").val() + " "); document.getElementById("txtEnglish").focus() }, 0);
    });
} //end onLoad function

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
```

C# .Net insertion code

```
public int insert(person d)
    {
        String Query;
        string ConnStr = new ConnectionClass().ConnStr();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            Query = "insert into UTF(ENGLISH_NAME, HINDI_NAME) VALUES('" + d.ENGLISH_NAME + "','" + d.HINDI_NAME + "')";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your `insert` code?

Comment: I'm using google API for english to hindi conversion

Comment: Do you have some code that you wrote to get data into your database?

Comment: I'm nor familiar with that, can you show the part when you actually inserting row, your sql query?

Comment: You're going to need this, if you do not have it: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/developer-suite/downloads/101202winsoft-087370.html -- you're going to need the Oracle Native client and you're going to have to setup a connection.  Are you familiar with TSNNames.ora?

Comment: Can you please use CommandParameters instead of concatenating strings to make a sqlstatement ... see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5427980/578411

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Query` to this (do not change, this part for knowledge purposes only):

```
Query = "insert into UTF(ENGLISH_NAME, HINDI_NAME) VALUES('" + d.ENGLISH_NAME + "',N'" + d.HINDI_NAME + "')";
```

You need prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N. Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.

### But!

(Actual part what you need to do)

use **Parameterized SQL queries**. [How and Why to Use Parameterized Queries](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/)

```
Query = "insert into UTF(ENGLISH_NAME, HINDI_NAME) VALUES( @ENGLISH_NAME, @HINDI_NAME)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ENGLISH_NAME",d.ENGLISH_NAME));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@HINDI_NAME",d.HINDI_NAME));
```

Comment: and that doesn't support named parameters

Comment: _"OleDB doesn't recognize named parameters, but it apparently does recognize that you're trying to convey a named parameter, so you can use that to your advantage and make your SQL semantic and easier to understand. So long as they're passed in the same order, it'll accept a variable as a named parameter."_, ref : [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675610/how-to-update-a-table-using-oledb-parameters).